# Discord.js Time command

Tags: discord.js

```
Const currentDate = new Date();
client.on('message', msg => {
  if(msg.author.bot) return;
  if(msg.content === `${prefix}time`) {
    msg.channel.send(currentDate.toLocaleString());
  }
})
```

This does provide the right time for MY timezone but is there anyway to make the bot send a time stamp, different regions see a different time?

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-timestamp-styles can be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use Discord's `<t:unix-timestamp:t>` feature. It'll vary depending on the timezone of the user seeing the message. You can get the Unix timestamp with `Date.now()` (`const unixTimestamp = Date.now()`) but that's the timestamp in milliseconds so you will need to divide it by 1000 for seconds.

You also want to use `Math.floor` since dividing milliseconds will give a decimal value and Discord's timestamp thing won't work.

`const unixTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)`

Here's the command using your *command handler*:

```js
client.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  if (msg.content === `${prefix}time`) {
    const unixTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    // you can remove the :t in the end so it's a full date
    // :t makes it only the time
    msg.channel.send(`The current time is <t:${unixTime}:t>`);
  }
});
```

Also, I recommend using `messageCreate` and not `message` as it's deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! I got close but it was 2 years off for some reason, this helped a lot